# How to create WordPress custom end point with multiple parameters?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, rest-api, wp-api, plugin-json-api

I want to get all WooCommerce orders from given date range. I can retrieve all orders at once. But I am confusing with passing the date range via API URL.

Can anybody help me with this? I know it's something like this but can't figure out the exact way to do it.

Here is my route:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('woo/v2', 'woocommerce/order_summary_by_date/(?P<start_date>/<end_date>)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'woocommerce_orders_by_dates'
    ));
});
```

This is function to access:

```
function woocommerce_orders_by_dates($start_date, $end_date) {
    $start_date = $start_date['start_date'];
    $end_date = $end_date['start_date'];

    return $start_date . $end_date;
}
```

URL is: `https://example.com/wp-json/woo/v2/woocommerce/order_summary_by_date/?start_date=2021-09-01&end_date=2021-09-30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a route, parameters accepted via the query string (eg. `?a=b&c=d`) are not registered as part of the endpoint, like you have done. Those parameters just need to be defined in the `args` property:

```
add_action(
    'rest_api_init',
    function() {
        register_rest_route(
            'woo/v2',
            'woocommerce/order_summary_by_date',
            array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'woocommerce_orders_by_dates'
                'args'     => array(
                    'start_date' => array(
                        'required' => true,
                    ),
                    'end_date'   => array(
                        'required' => true,
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
);
```

You can also defined sanitization and validation callbacks for the arguments. This is all described in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments).

To access the values you use the `$request` object passed to the callback:

```
function woocommerce_orders_by_dates( $request ) {
    $start_date = $request->get_param( 'start_date' );
    $end_date   = $request->get_param( 'end_date' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.